# How are reconstructed surfaces named?

Tags: surfaces, terminology

I am trying to understand the terminology of reconstructed surfaces.
Simple surfaces such as 2x2 or 1x1 make sense to me. For instance, figure 1 of the paper https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1574798 shows a layer of the 2x2 supercell that is easy to understand.

[image]

However, the reconstructed surfaces have names like $$ \sqrt{31} \times \sqrt{31} $$ or $$  \sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3} $$ at times also followed by R30 (or some other angle), which is hard (for me as a beginner) to understand.
Could someone explain these or point to some useful resources to learn about them?

Comment: Please refer to the answers to the following questions 
1. [understanding-square-root-notation-of-supercell](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/help-understanding-square-root-notation-of-supercell)
2. [rotation-matrix-of-root-integer-notation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10937/how-to-get-rotation-matrix-elements-from-root-integer-notation/10961#10961)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Was the comment by @VandanRevanur helpful?